# Line in the tag <span> with CSS

Tags: css, line

I have problems with this line:

[image: This line]

How can I do this line in the tag `<span>` with CSS?

Can you help me?

Comment: Please explain. What kind of problem do you have with this line and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the picture

Comment: @Develop4: That seems like a normal straight line which you can do with borders. I am not sure what problems you are having in creating this line. Maybe showing us your code and what problems you faced could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obJEmE

```
   <span class="with-line">
     <span class="with-line-left-border"> </span>
   </span>

body {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1e88e5;
}

.with-line {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  top: 220px;
}

.with-line .with-line-left-border {
  width: 3px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
```

I'm not sure if you want this, for the next time, explain your problem a bit more.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! XD Greetings

Comment: Man and how I can put this line in the left and right side of my page?

Comment: Try to add "float: left" or "float: right" and remove "margin: auto".

Comment: Or change position: relative to position: absolute, and left: 0 or right: 0.